# make the scanner scan the entire paper pages, not skip anything near the borders?

Tags: pdf, scanner

I am scanning some paper pages using the document feeder of Xerox WorkCentre 7830.

The scanner didn't scan the entire paper pages, and skip some part near the borders of the paper pages.

For example, here is a page from [my scanned pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/cut1.pdf). the handwrittend  "Regular surface" on the right is cut off by the scanner to be *Regular su".

However in the scanner control panel, I have specified the custom scan area to be slighly larger than the paper page size.This is also indicated by the white margins in the pdf page.

I have also choose 0.0 for Edge Erase option.

So how can I make the scanner scan the entire paper pages, and do not skip anything near the borders of the paper pages?

Thanks.

Comment: So did you get this working?  Did a reduction setting capture the whole sheet?

Comment: I haven't got access to the scanner these days. When I try it next time, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are bumping up against the size of the scan area.  There are a number of workarounds:

- Instead of tightening the paper guides against the page to center it, open them up so they are maybe 3/4" wider than the sheet (allow extra width of a little more than twice as much as what is being cut off in the scan).  Feed the page tight against the guide on the side of the page that is a copy of the binding.  That will move the wasted image of the page binding out of the scan area and move the cut-off portion into range.  The page guides are shown in the red rectangles:
  [image]
- Trim the original to remove as much of the image of the binding as is being cut off by the scan on the other side.  Feed the trimmed side of the page tight against the guide (leave the guides set to a normal page width).  This will shift the page over to bring the portion previously unscanned into the scan area.
- Use the flatbed instead of the document feeder.  Position the page so that the image of the binding is what is out of view and all of what you want is in the scanned area.
- Use a small reduction setting.  A value of around 91% to 93% is typically used for a "fit entire page" feature, but you can calculate the percentage based on the width of what is actually being scanned vs. the actual width of the content.

Comment: Thanks. by "guides" do you mean the two slide-able things in the document feeder, shown as in red rectangles in [this picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/scanner/scanner.png)? The original image is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/scanner/scanner.gif)

Comment: Right.  Set those wider than the sheet.  They typically move in tandem so that a sheet as wide as the guides is centered.  Use the extra space to offset the sheet so the important side is in the scan area and the extra, wasted space where the binding was copied is what gets cut off.  Guiding the paper on one edge is usually enough to keep it straight.

Comment: Thanks. I placed the pages in portrait orientation, and I think you guessed that I placed them in landscape orientation. So I actually placed the paper page so that its binding side faced the entry into the scanner.

Comment: I hadn't guessed that.  Did you try just flipping the page 180 degrees?

Comment: I flipped other paper pages (not the one shown) 180 degree, so the binding side of the paper page is facing the outside. But there are notations written on the four sides' margins. So I hope there is a solution for that using the feeder

Comment: If there are notations potentially on all sides, use the last workaround (a reduction setting).  Most copiers that have a "fit whole page" setting do it that way.